# Problems using POST with a Multi Step Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I have a 3 stage form where users input data and I want to use the POST command so the data is usuable on another page. When using a single form POST works fine as below

```
<form action="otherpage.php" method="post">
Question:  <input type="text" name="something" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

However now, I have a 3 stage form where the user enters some data at each stage. The screen transitions are using jquery and everyone seemingly works fine other than using POST.

```
<form id="msform" action="otherpage.php" method="post">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Screen1</li>
        <li>Screen2</li>
        <li>Screen3</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Title</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Question?</h3>
        <input type="text" name="variable1" placeholder="blah" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Student Status</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Are you are student?</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="student" value="yes" checked>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="student" value="no">No
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Dropdown</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Dropdown Question?</h3>
        <select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Now when I go to click the submit button, I no longer get taken to "otherpage.php"

I have tried wrapping the submit button around form tags and posting but that also doesn't work. I am a novice when it comes to this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:-

This is the javascript code if it helps:

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return true;
})
```

Edit 2:

Perhaps, because I am now using javascript where as before I wasn't, it means that I cant use POST in the same way as before? I have been searching other peoples questions and the internet but really cant find out the next step to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I actually solved it, I needed to remove the code:

```
class="submit action-button"
```

from my submit button as that was preventing me use the 'POST' command and instead was calling the jquery file which just had a return:true inside of it.

I think I was just being an idiot!

Comment: also, if anyone else experiences this, ensure within JADE you set the FORM to a FORM element not a DIV.
    form#msform(action='/home', method='get')